# Importing 3d objects and texture at run-time through server

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to figure how can I load models and textures in the most efficient way with Unity3D at run-time, so far I've read about glTF formats, Draco API, and currently I've implemented a simple procedure which works really slow. I'm using BestHTTP and for textures I'm doing this:

```
var texFoundPath = Directory.GetFiles(outFolder, texFileName, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Single();
                            Debug.Log("Loading texture from " + texFoundPath);

                            var texBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(texFoundPath);

                            Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(2,2);
                            tex.LoadImage(texBytes);
```

And using ObjImporter for importing objects.

```
var gameObject = ObjImporter.Import(objStr, mtlStr, textureHashtable);
```

So at run-time, models that are 3-5mb takes up to 3-5 seconds to load. Which is very slow and not suitable for anything. Doing this locally will result in a 200-300mb apk if I have around 100 models.

So currently I'm looking for a way to do this efficiently, and would love your help. I think it'll be the best to load the models with Draco API. but my I'm not sure how to create the plugin that will communicate with that API.

Comment: Have you considered Asset Bundles?

Comment: @Hristo Yes. and it's a no-go. It's slow like what I'm doing now. Here's a ref to prove it: https://answers.unity.com/questions/10868/how-to-build-asset-bundles-at-runtime-from-a-serve.html

Comment: Well those answers and the post are from 2010. Also I'm currently using asset bundles and it takes ~ 5 seconds to download and load an asset bundle of 2-3 mb in the app

Answer (score 0):

1 MB per second isn't a bad download speed. Really the only option without using prediction is to lower the resolution of your textures and make them smaller, compress your texture files into "chunks" and download each "chunk" as needed, uncompress, and apply to models, but that would probably still take a good amount of time.

I think what you really want is to have some prediction logic that loads "bundles" of assets before they are actually needed, and store them in memory for later use.

For instance, if the player is 200 meters away from a house that needs to be downloaded before viewing, and the players view distance is 100 meters, then start downloading the house. By the time the house is within viewing distance of the player, it will be downloaded and ready to use.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but if you have a UI with 20 models in it, and you need swipe left/right between them, I want them to instantiate instantly.

Comment: I see two possible options for that scenario... IF there is enough time to download those 20 models before the player can get to that menu then I would start downloading them as soon as runtime initiates (you could even "stream" the models in as they download, but at least the first 5-10 might be downloaded and ready by the time the player gets there. OR, you can separate the models into what is needed instantly (or used 3,000+ times in your game) and those models should be saved exclusively in the project folder for faster load times, while the rest can wait to be downloaded.

Comment: I know it seems dumb separating all of your models between being saved locally and being stored on a server but it's actually the logical approach when you have, for instance, a box that is used multiple times throughout the entire game.

Comment: Yeah I thought about it. But downloading 20 models which takes up to 1 minute isn't good for me. There're categories - every category may have 20-30 models. When the app launched the user can choose any category he wants, and what then? let him wait 1 minute for the specific 20 models of that category? Of course after the models have been loaded once I save them locally, but until then.. I need to figure out how to import them within about 0.2 second per a model of 2~3MB.

Comment: Right.... Well, the only option I can think of that could possibly help is to download every category synchronously and pop each model into memory as it is downloaded. When it's time to load the model into the scene, if it's downloaded, great! If not, then maybe put a "Loading.." placeholder? Unfortunately this is completely dependent upon the connection speed of the server, and the speed of the client, so there really aren't many code optimizations that could help.

Comment: It won't be good enough too. Currently we're using a free hosting server, we're planning to move into AWS asap. and then I'll try to implement Draco/glTF loader and compare the run-time results.

Comment: Firebase is also a great option. They have very fast reliable storage and have a Unity plugin. Not sure if AWS has unity integration.